Verification of Initial Conditions in an RLC Circuit (buck converter, inductor current)
I had drawn the following circuit (note that all components are ideal and european standard):

Suppose the following Situation:

\$t<0\$: The MOSFET was open for a very long time
\$t=0\$: The MOSFET is closed

Tasks:

What is the current \$i_L\$ through the inductor \$L\$ at \$t=0\$ (initial condition 1)?
What is the slope of the current \$i_L\$ through the inductor \$L\$ at \$t=0\$ (initial condition 2)?

Question:

Could somebody please check if my derivation of the initial conditions is clear and understandable?

My Solution:

For \$t<0\$: I simplified the circuit as shown below. Since the MOSFET was off for a very long time, all voltages and currents are zero.



For \$t=0\$: I simplified the circuit as shown below. Since the current \$i_L\$ through the inductor \$L\$ cannot change instantaneously, the initial condition is \$i_L(t=0)=0\$A. Using Kirchhoff's Voltage Law, we have \$-U_q+u_L+u_C=0\$. We also know that the voltage across the capacitor \$u_C\$ cannot change instantaneously and must be zero. Therefore, \$U_q=u_L=L\cdot di_L/dt\$. Thus, the second initial condition is \$di_L/dt(t=0)=U_q/L\$.


Thank you for your help!

I'm not familiar with your schematic symbols. But I take it that $U_q$ is a voltage source with some polarity I cannot fathom. (No idea which end is positive.) Regardless, how could there be any current in the inductor at $t=0$? Also, the capacitor must have $0:\text{V}$ across it at $t=0$. So isn't it obvious what the slope of the current in the inductor must be?


For t<0: I simplified the circuit as shown below. Since the MOSFET
was off for a very long time, all voltages and currents are zero.

Correct.

For t=0

The full supply voltage appears across the inductor but I have no idea why you are showing the arrows the way you do. However, ignoring the arrows we would resort to the standard inductor formula: -
$$V_L = L\cdot \dfrac{di_L}{dt}$$

Hence, \$\dfrac{di_L}{dt} = \dfrac{V_S}{L}\$ (which appears to be what you are saying).

‚First thanks for answering. Regarding the arrows: I was drawing them because I used Kirchhoffs Voltage Law $-U_q+u_L+u_C=0$. In your circuit it is $-V_q-V_L-V_C=0$, right? Which makes sense when $u_C=V_C=0$ then $U_q=u_L$ or $V_s=-V_L$. so you have a negative slope what means that your arrow must be pointed in the other direction, right?

Are you showing electric fields with arrows (as they do in some parts of Europe but not in UK or USA)? If you are showing voltages then your arrows are incorrect and mine are correct.

and the arrow of Vs is pointing from minus to plus in your circuit?

Yes, if I'd have shown the arrow that would be correct @MarcoMoldenhauer
